# Get a screenshot of a specific application

Tags: c#, winapi, screenshot

I know I can get the screenshot of the entire screen using Graphics.CopyFromScreen(). However, what if I just want the screenshot of a specific application?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started:

```
public void CaptureApplication(string procName)
{
    var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName)[0];
    var rect = new User32.Rect();
    User32.GetWindowRect(proc.MainWindowHandle, ref rect);

    int width = rect.right - rect.left;
    int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(rect.left, rect.top, 0, 0, new Size(width, height), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    }

    bmp.Save("c:\\tmp\\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}

private class User32
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Rect
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);
}
```

It works, but needs improvement:

- You may want to use a different mechanism to get the process handle (or at least do some defensive coding)
- If your target window isn't in the foreground, you'll end up with a screenshot that's the right size/position, but will just be filled with whatever is in the foreground (you probably want to pull the given window into the foreground first)
- You probably want to do something other than just save the bmp to a temp directory

Comment: this doesn't bring the window for the selected process to the foreground in win7, so you will get a screenshot with the active window

Comment: @alconja i used your code to take a snapshot of notepad .but it took a snapshot of visual studio which was the active window .can we use this to take a picture of none active window ?

Comment: @FastSnail - I was going to suggest you try the other answer, but I see from your comments that that isn't working either... Another option might be to try to find a pinvoke method that pulls the target app/window into the foreground first. For example, [SwitchToThisWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.switchtothiswindow), maybe...

Comment: Does it work if the window is hidden or minimized? CopyScreen would create exception if screen is locked right?

Comment: @daisy - it's been a while, but no I think this one just takes a screenshot of a region of the screen, so won't work if the window isn't visible. The answer below claims to work in that instance (not sure about locked screens though, sorry).

Comment: for opengl process this is not working, any suggestions?

Answer (score 126):

> If you want to print form screen you can use

```
PrintWindow(Handle);
```

The PrintWindow win32 api will capture a window bitmap even if the window is covered by other windows or if it is off screen:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);

public static Bitmap PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd)    
{       
    RECT rc;        
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);
   
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);        
    Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);        
    IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();        

    PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);  
  
    gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);               
    gfxBmp.Dispose(); 
   
    return bmp;   
}
```

The reference to RECT above can be resolved with the following class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    private int _Left;
    private int _Top;
    private int _Right;
    private int _Bottom;

    public RECT(RECT Rectangle) : this(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom)
    {
    }
    public RECT(int Left, int Top, int Right, int Bottom)
    {
        _Left = Left;
        _Top = Top;
        _Right = Right;
        _Bottom = Bottom;
    }

    public int X {
        get { return _Left; }
        set { _Left = value; }
    }
    public int Y {
        get { return _Top; }
        set { _Top = value; }
    }
    public int Left {
        get { return _Left; }
        set { _Left = value; }
    }
    public int Top {
        get { return _Top; }
        set { _Top = value; }
    }
    public int Right {
        get { return _Right; }
        set { _Right = value; }
    }
    public int Bottom {
        get { return _Bottom; }
        set { _Bottom = value; }
    }
    public int Height {
        get { return _Bottom - _Top; }
        set { _Bottom = value + _Top; }
    }
    public int Width {
        get { return _Right - _Left; }
        set { _Right = value + _Left; }
    }
    public Point Location {
        get { return new Point(Left, Top); }
        set {
            _Left = value.X;
            _Top = value.Y;
        }
    }
    public Size Size {
        get { return new Size(Width, Height); }
        set {
            _Right = value.Width + _Left;
            _Bottom = value.Height + _Top;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator Rectangle(RECT Rectangle)
    {
        return new Rectangle(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Height);
    }
    public static implicit operator RECT(Rectangle Rectangle)
    {
        return new RECT(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom);
    }
    public static bool operator ==(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
    {
        return Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
    {
        return !Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "{Left: " + _Left + "; " + "Top: " + _Top + "; Right: " + _Right + "; Bottom: " + _Bottom + "}";
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ToString().GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(RECT Rectangle)
    {
        return Rectangle.Left == _Left && Rectangle.Top == _Top && Rectangle.Right == _Right && Rectangle.Bottom == _Bottom;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object Object)
    {
        if (Object is RECT) {
            return Equals((RECT)Object);
        } else if (Object is Rectangle) {
            return Equals(new RECT((Rectangle)Object));
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution. I just want to point out that sometimes PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb gives white artifacts. In that case just try to use some other format instead, such as PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb

Comment: not if its minimized though, also it makes the window you are targeting flicker when you PrintWindow()

Comment: how do i use this method? PrintWindow(`what to pass here`)

Comment: The HWND of the top level window you would like to get an image of

Comment: how can I get a HWND?

Comment: @MauriceFlanagan i'm getting entirely black image ?why??

Comment: @FastSnail Probably because it's a DirectX window, I think there is some way to capture them on Windows 10 but haven't looked into it

Comment: Thanks for this. Just in case somebody else had to look it up, The referencefor DLLimport is `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Comment: @FastSnail I had the same issue. I guess you are starting a new process and want to capture that. The problem is, that your window is not initialized yet. This is the case even if you call `Process.WaitForIdle()`. I am a simple man and wrapped the extern call to `GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);` into a do-while loop, with `rc.Width == 0 || rc.Height == 0` as the exit condition.

Comment: Has the black image solution been added to this solution? I'm running into the same thing on Windows 10

Comment: @Seva To get the HWND use this `this.Handle`

Comment: Always a black bitmap for UWP apps. I can't even seem to get DWM thumbnails for a UWP app while I'm on the same desktop as the UWP app. However, I can get the DWM thumbnail for a UWP app when I'm not on the same desktop as it. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: What is the cause when the result of picture is black?

Comment: @CodeGuru: for non-UWP apps, likely the window is not visible. Check out GetWindowLongPtr with GWL_STYLE and compare against WS_VISIBLE

Comment: I found a solution to the black image problem. Try putting in the value of 2 as the 3rd parameter (flags) for `PrintWindow`. After some digging I found the following in the chromium source: _"The PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT flag is undocumented, but works starting in Windows 8.1. It allows for capturing the contents of the window that are drawn using DirectComposition."_ `UINT flags = PW_CLIENTONLY | PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT;`
 and so I do: 
`int PW_CLIENTONLY = 0x1; int PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT = 0x2;
PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, PW_CLIENTONLY | PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT);`

Comment: Thank you jargon. I was so happy I found your comment, help me out immensely. I was worried I would need to start using directx to capture the screen and rewrite everything.

Answer (score 9):

Based on Alconja's answer, I made a few improvements:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rect
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);

public Bitmap CaptureApplication(string procName)
{
    Process proc;

    // Cater for cases when the process can't be located.
    try
    {
        proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName)[0];
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // You need to focus on the application
    SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
    ShowWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, SW_RESTORE);

    // You need some amount of delay, but 1 second may be overkill
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    Rect rect = new Rect();
    IntPtr error = GetWindowRect(proc.MainWindowHandle, ref rect);

    // sometimes it gives error.
    while (error == (IntPtr)0)
    {
        error = GetWindowRect(proc.MainWindowHandle, ref rect);
    }

    int width = rect.right - rect.left;
    int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics.FromImage(bmp).CopyFromScreen(rect.left,
                                           rect.top,
                                           0,
                                           0,
                                           new Size(width, height),
                                           CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: after skimming through this i noticed that, if the process closes during the `Thread.Sleep(1000);` you will have an infinite loop.

Comment: @NicolasTyler is right. To clarify, the issue is that calling `GetWindowRect` with an HWND that is no longer valid will always return zero, meaning that the `while` loop in this answer will never exit and just burn CPU forever, which is a pretty serious bug. But otherwise I think this answer is an elegant solution. Maybe just limit to a fixed number of retries, and maybe sleeping a little in between. Or don't retry in this method.

Comment: This answer also doesn't dispose the `Graphics` object.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [P/Invoking](http://www.pinvoke.net/) the win32 way of doing this, [an article to this effect](http://www.fengyuan.com/article/wmprint.html)... sort of.

Basically, go through the trouble of setting up a DC to a bitmap and send WM_PRINT to the application window in question.  Its pretty nasty, all told, but may work for you.

Functions you may need: [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx), [GetDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871(VS.85).aspx), [CreateCompatibleBitmp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183488(VS.85).aspx), and [SelectObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957(VS.85).aspx).

I can't say I've ever done this before, but this is how I'd attack the problem.  (Well, I'd probably do it in pure C but still; roughly the way I'd attack it).