# how to read a datagridview of another application

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, datagridview, ui-automation

I want to read a 'DataGridView' of an application. There is an application in which many child windows are there. Here is a picture of that application and the window containing the datagridview which I want to read, I've highlighted the window which I want to read

[image: application]

I've searched the window through UISPY and here is the picture of the window and datagridview in it. I've highlighted the control which I want to be read.

[image]

I've used this code(Winapi) to read the control but I am getting an empty string

```
public object WindowText(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    object obj2 = "";
    if (hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        return "";
    }
    // 0x111 is WM_COMMAND
    MainModule.SendMessage(hWnd, 0x111, (IntPtr)0x81eb, IntPtr.Zero);
    MainModule.StrData = MainModule.StrData + Clipboard.GetText();
    // 0x307 is WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD
    MainModule.SendMessage(hWnd, 0x307, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    return obj2;
}
```

I've also tried UI Automation but i didn't succeed in reading through it also.
The datagridview has some cells which are updated every second(Live data) and I want to read it and store it.
I want to read the the cells and columns(Symbol,Bid,Ask) and the cell contents(AUDCAD,AUDCHF) etc.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with these `SendMessage`

Comment: its a winapi instance of reading the contents of another application like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/rnvwI.jpg

Comment: Try WM_GETTEXT http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx If this is not a custom control then each cell should contain an "edit"-control. For example Powerbuilder has a grid control which hasn't edit controls. they draw the whole control and not a list of edit controls.

Comment: Try this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488304/how-to-capture-data-in-a-window**. maybe you can use the information provided there, as there are some similarities.

Answer (score 0):

UI Spy uses [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not windows messages.  Since the control claims to be a datagrid, you should be able to [find the item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff625913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by looking for the element with `UIA_ControlTypePropertyId` equal to `UIA_DataGridControlTypeId`, and then examining the children as appropriate.