# C# Virtual Mouse Console application Running in the background

Tags: c#, mouse, leap-motion

Hi i need help with my program, i made a console application in c# and Leap Motion Device, my program simulates a virtual mouse, moving the cursor and Left/Right click, using

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
```

and

```
public static void MouseClickLeft(int x, int y) 
        {

            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
        }

        public static void MouseClickRight(int x, int y)
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
        }
```

I need run this program with another app, but the mouse control only works if the Console application its running as the main window, its stops working when i do the left click in the desktop or another app. Im beginner in programming with c#, there is anything that i can do to make this running in the background and still moving the mouse?

Answer (score 2):

To receive Leap Motion tracking data when your application is not the foreground application, you have to set the background frames policy:

```
controller.SetPolicyFlags(Controller.PolicyFlag.POLICYBACKGROUNDFRAMES);
```

You can call this function anytime, but the result is asynchronous, so the policyFlags property won't show the change right away.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my Key Clone application for an example how this is done:
https://github.com/Mataniko/WowKeyclone/blob/master/Interop.cs

In my case i'm setting a hook with WH_KEYBOARD_LL in your case use WH_MOUSE_LL.

Additional information on setting hooks can be found at: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx

Let me know in a comment if you need more information.

Comment: You can basically use the entire class with a couple of edits

Comment: I take a look at your program , but i cant understand, i want to make this console app work with a Game Maker .exe, like the output of the mouse app turns into the input of the game.

Comment: You will have to hook into that window handle and send input. This is not a straight forward thing to do. Look at the KeyHandler.cs file in the same project on how to send those events to another window. There are also a lot of examples on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355286/programmatically-mouse-click-in-another-window

Comment: i used

`[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern UInt32 SendInput(UInt32 nInputs,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1)] INPUT[] pInputs,
          Int32 cbSize);`

and System.Windows.Forms with Cursor.Position and it works, thx!

Comment: Great, if your problem is solved make sure you accept an answer, good luck with your application.