# What software can I use to write a bot that can click in x,y coordinates of a minimized window (non-web based)

Tags: bots

I want to write a bot that does repetitive click actions for a game. But it must work in a minimized window so that I can use my computer and have control of my mouse and keyboard. Is this easy to do? If so what software would I have to download to write it. If you know of something I could use does it also have keyboard input or any other special features (not required but good to know for myself and others). The game is in a separate client that is not web-based.

Comment: Smells like a cheater. You will need to code. Find the window handle and then send a click message . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355286/programmatically-mouse-click-in-another-window

Comment: By the way, I HATE cheaters.

Comment: Ok this looks promising, what software do I have to download for this? MS visual basic 2012? I've started to download the software from here, the first 2.4GB file. http://tensoftwares.net/windows/visual-studio/visual-studio-2012/visual-studio-2012-free-download

Comment: It is to you to choose the language. Almost all so-called "desktop languages" can take the window handle and send messages. Delphi, C++, VB...

Comment: Hmm, I think this might be out of my league. From some more research I have seen that you can run a regular bot that isn't minimized in a virtual machine which is minimized. So I can set up the bot and then minimize the virtual machine and have it running in the background, do you think this will work considering I have some basic bots that already work?

Comment: The SO in VM can't know if it is minimized or not because it is a host machine concept. Good approach. VirtualBox you do not even need to have a window. After boot and setup the VM SO you can close the virtualized window AND the VirtualBox software. You can get it again by running VirtualBox and selecting the running VM. Everything runs in background.

Comment: My fault. If you want to close everything you must run your guest SO in headless mode and access it by a remote console. Don't know if works with Window$$ guest. Sorry. I'm only using Ubuntu Server. But you can go ahead with your plan. It will work.

Comment: I'll advise you: I hope you will not funk with my Battlefield game.... I hate cheaters.

Comment: XD don't worry I don't play Battlefield. The bot I will be running will rarely be running over an hour. It's mainly so I can play my game in the background without my parents being pissed at me for gaming and not working =/.

Comment: Sounds like you are leveling up some char... I already own a lanhouse once and I remember the kids puting paper clips to hold down the keys to level up some MU characters untl they ate burgers... well... Good luck.