# Mouse Wheel Event is not raised in second monitor

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, opengl, .net-4.6.2

I am testing my desktop application when using two monitors and adjust them to Extend display.

I use the mouse wheel for zooming in and out but it is not working when the application is displayed on the second monitor. The mouse wheel event is not even raised when debugging using breakpoints.

Everything works fine when displaying the application on the first monitor. 
I thought it is a windows issue but I tested other purchased applications work fine on both monitors.

I am using `.NET Framework 4.6.2`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

if the windows form didn't help with your problem you can use windows api mouse events to handle your issue.
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event
also you can use this comment to help you listen for the mouse events.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10355905/9323061