# Mirror window's context menu using WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

i'm writing a window manager for Windows 7,  at this time i can mirror any window using some interop code, but what about the window's context menus? Like notepad, when using the window in 3D space, the context menu is shown where the window is (the WM used shows on top of all the windows, mirror all the desktop windows as opengl rectangles, takes a screenshot for each window and uses SendMessage to handle the mouse clicks to the selected window). [Bug example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ifg5.png).
The code used to mirror any window is taken from [this page](https://www.cyotek.com/blog/capturing-screenshots-using-csharp-and-p-invoke), and the clicks are sent using code from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355286/programmatically-mouse-click-in-another-window).
So, there is any method to mirror the context menu, and manage it? Isn't necessary to do it in 3D, i need to manage it in 2D.

Comment: Please consider posting [MCVE].

Comment: Thanks! I'll add the code which can be used to mirror any window