# Capturing and reading screenshots from process

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using the following code to take screenshots from a process:

[Get a screenshot of a specific application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891345/get-a-screenshot-of-a-specific-application) (Maurice Flanagan's answer)

I would like to read data from the process screenshot quite frequently. It takes about 100ms for the method to execute once. My idea is to put it inside a timer which updates a few times per second. I suppose this will "freeze" the app each time the method runs (since I run it on the main thread).

So what I would like to know is; what kind of asynchronous solution would fit this scenario best? I know that there are some built-in classes for this. I just need a pointer in the right direction (not very familiar with WinForms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the BackgroundWorker class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx