# C# PrintWindow only works once

Tags: c#, api, user-interface, process

So I'm using the code in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/911225/979732

When I use printwindow in a timer to continually display another program within mine, the code only works once. Then, every time I close the application and reopen it the image is exactly the same as the first time the code is executed, which is really strange. Only if I close the application I'm capturing, and reopen it the image changes. So the code only works once per application. I need it to keep giving a new image every time it is executed (which is about 30 times per second).

If there is another way to do this, I'm all ears. I just need to copy another program's display, since I'm trying to create a proxy-ish application, that redirects input to the other application while overlaying some controls of my own.

Thanks!

Comment: don't just link to code, show us exactly how you implmented it.