# Simulate user interaction with a game

Tags: android, user-interaction

Typically, when playing a game, a user is displayed in real time a bitmap representing the game state (what is actually displayed on the screen) and can send touch events to the game by touching the screen.

Is it possible for an application to programmatically get the output image of an android game and send screen touch events to it without the need for the user to unlock the device or put the game foreground (i.e letting it run in the background) ?

I know it is possible in Windows (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891345/get-a-screenshot-of-a-specific-application)) so I guess there must be a way to do it in other OSs