# C# get pixel color from another window

Tags: c#, getpixel

I want to get a pixel color from another window. The code I have is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

sealed class Win32
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
    
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern Int32 ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);
    
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int nXPos, int nYPos);
    
    static public System.Drawing.Color GetPixelColor(int x, int y)
    {
        IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
        uint pixel = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
        ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
        Color color = Color.FromArgb((int)(pixel & 0x000000FF),
            (int)(pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8,
            (int)(pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
        return color;
    }
}
```

The problem is that this code is scanning the whole screen which is not what I want. The idea is to modify the code to scan for pixel color based on another application screen boundaries. Maybe something with `FindWindow` or `GetWindow`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can import `FindWindow` as you said to find windows by the caption:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

static IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(string caption)
{
    return FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, caption);
}
```

Then, add an extra param to your `GetPixelColor` with the handler:

```
static public System.Drawing.Color GetPixelColor(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y)
{
    IntPtr hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    uint pixel = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    Color color = Color.FromArgb((int)(pixel & 0x000000FF),
                    (int)(pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8,
                    (int)(pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
    return color;
}
```

Usage:

```
var title = "windows caption";

var hwnd = FindWindowByCaption(title);

var pixel = Win32.GetPixelColor(hwnd, x, y);
```

Comment: The big problem with this (for anyone who wants to scan the whole screen, not the OP) is it's inefficient with the many P/Invoke calls. If you're using it for more than a few pixels it is going to be too slow. You could pipe the entire image to a Bitmap object and then access the scan0 pointer for faster speed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/911225/881111

Comment: Offtopic, but further reading on why GetPixel this is slow, including interesting alternatives in the comments: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211223-00/?p=106050