# NodeJS get pixel color from another window

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

How can you access the color of a pixel on the screen using NodeJS?

My use-case is for Windows, but a cross-platform solution would be ideal.

Here's an example in C# which could be helpful: [C# get pixel color from another window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056321/c-sharp-get-pixel-color-from-another-window)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up converting the linked C# answer to NodeJS by using [node-ffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi):

```
import ffi from "ffi";
import chroma from "chroma-js";

var user32 = new ffi.Library("user32", {
    "GetDC": ["int32", ["int32"]],
    "ReleaseDC": ["int32", ["int32", "int32"]],
});
var gdi32 = new ffi.Library("gdi32", {
    "GetPixel": ["uint32", ["int32", "int32", "int32"]],
});

export function GetPixelColor(x: number, y: number) {
    let hdc = user32.GetDC(0);
    let pixel = gdi32.GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
    user32.ReleaseDC(0, hdc);
    let color = chroma(pixel & 0x000000FF, (pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8, (pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
    return color.hex().substr(1); // to match with robotjs.getPixelColor() returns
}
```

To use:

```
let pixelColor = GetPixelColor(0, 0);
console.log("Color: #" + pixelColor);
```

**UPDATE**

Since then, I put together this library: https://github.com/Venryx/windows-ffi

It supports screenshotting of regions of the screen, rather than just individual pixels. This makes it much faster for reading image-data over an area, and is the solution I use nowadays.

---

#### Alternatives

- windows-ss: https://github.com/Sxxov/windows-ss
- screenshot-desktop: https://github.com/bencevans/screenshot-desktop
- desktop-screenshot: https://github.com/johnvmt/node-desktop-screenshot

> Note: Does not have a built-in way to access the raw pixel data. (you'd have to read and parse the file manually)

- RobotJS: https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs

> Warning: It currently causes crashes if you call getPixelColor when a UAC prompt is open. ([see issue](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/issues/495))

Comment: I've been having issues with getPixelColor(x,y) myself. I found that setMouseDelay() set to 0 does not affect getPixelColor(). The latter slows down my macro substantially.