# How to get pixel color of windows behind other windows

Tags: c#, winforms, pixel

How can i get pixel color of windows that I alt + tab (not minimize)? 
I tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37056321/10400870) but it seem only work with active windows. All help appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: You can't because it may not even exist in a buffer anywhere (the window might get completely redrawn on demand)

Comment: Windows that belong to your application, or windows that belong to other applications?

Comment: @J... Windows that belong to my application

Comment: @DoanVanThang  That's an important detail that you should [edit] into your question.

Comment: @J... I misunderstand your meaning, both windows belong to 2 different application (Ex: Chrome and Discord)