# Is it possible to get Window/Form instance from its Handle(IntPtr)?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am able to get the window handle value of an application and to capture the whole window. but I need to capture only client rectangle of that Form/Window, so I need respective instance from the handle (either it is form or window).

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

```
Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(fileName);
IntPtr handle = p[0].MainWindowHandle;
```

Comment: So you want the client rect of a window in another process? You could p/invoke GetClientRect()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture screen of Window by handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931433/capture-screen-of-window-by-handle)

Comment: I have already tried GetClientRect() and ClientToScreen() methods from user32.dll. but not working

Comment: so that, i'm trying to get the form instance. So that i can use Form.ClientSize property

Comment: You simply cannot convert an external window into a Form instance.  GetClientRect() is the correct approach, if your code does not work then that's another issue.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

```
Control.FormHandle(handler);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I think, this will return control instance only, not Form or Window. because I tried this, it returns null.