# UWP : Using WPF app to get a screenshot of a specific application

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I need to write an app that shows all the running UWP apps and has next to the name of the app the screen shot of that app (what it is currently doing). Very similar to this:[Get a screenshot of a specific application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891345/get-a-screenshot-of-a-specific-application)

So I need to get handles of apps, and then as above from the handle get the screen shot of each app.

My app is a WPF C# app. So what APIs do I need to do this?