# Take screenshot in process window

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a screenshot to the window of a process in Windows 7 64 bit, the problem is that I always get error in the following line:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap (width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

Saying "invalid parameters", I made a throw to see the errors and width and height are always 0.

Before in 32 bits it worked well, but now in 64 bits it does not work anymore.

The code :

```
public void CaptureApplication()
{
    string procName = "firefox";

    var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName)[0];
    var rect = new User32.Rect();
    User32.GetWindowRect(proc.MainWindowHandle, ref rect);

    int width = rect.right - rect.left;
    int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(rect.left, rect.top, 0, 0, new Size(width, height), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

    bmp.Save("c:\\tmp\\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}

private class User32
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Rect
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Maybe because the process name is `firefox.exe`?

Comment: I did it, and it's the same error.

Comment: You should also check the return value of the `GetWindowRect` - if it returns `IntPtr.Zero`, something went wrong in that step.

Comment: I already tried it, it's always zero, I do not understand why, before I was good at 32 bits

Comment: Does it work with `Handle` instead of `MainWindowHandle`?

Comment: No, same error.

Comment: How many entries are returned by GetProcessesByName? I don't have FireFox but testing with both GoogleChrome & Internet Explorer the rectangle returned for entry 0 has all 4 bounds as 0, but if I check the next element in the array (var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName)[1];
) I get sensible values for the rectangle. With internet explorer I have 1 instance & 5 tabs - this results in 5 processes returned. Chrome on the other hand has 6 processes for a single instance with a single tab.

Comment: Process.GetProcessesByName(nombre_proceso).Length return 3

Comment: I check with Chrome and is the same error.

Comment: OK - so now you know there are 3 processes - you will need to find which is the correct one.

Comment: Process.GetProcessesByName(nombre_proceso)[2] work, but I get a photo of visual studio

Comment: Is Visual Studio on top of firefox? Your code seems to have been taken from the initial answer to this question - the following answer shows you how to display the application in order to capture the screenshot : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891345/get-a-screenshot-of-a-specific-application

Comment: it's strange with the process `string procName = "notepad";` it works... but with `"chrome"` it doesn't, same error

Comment: yes, when the program worked, it found the firefox window anyway

Comment: @M.Schena: if you check the task manager you will see that when NotePad starts there is just a single instance - so GetProcessesByName returns an array length 1 so array element 0 is always correct. When other application like Internet Explorer, Google Chrome & FireFox open then multiple processes all with the same name are started - in the case of the OP there are 3 & it is not the first array entry that is the active window.

Comment: @PaulF i now installed firefox, and runs several instances, but worked with above code... perhaps i just lucked the right process

Comment: @Chris - I didn't read far enough either - the last answer suggests using PrintWindow & that should work even if the application isn't topmost.

Comment: it seems that the problem is firefox, try with sublimetext and I get it working, I'm going to do a for to find the indicated process

Comment: This explains what is happening with FireFox : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1172713 - I haven't found how t find the main process yet.

Comment: @PaulF i think i found it out. have a look at my solution and give feedback please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the process of firefox returns an array of processes and you are looking for the one with an rectangle with realistic sizes which is the main process.

```
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName);
var rect = new User32.Rect();
int width = 0;
int height = 0:
foreach (Process proc in procs)
{
    User32.GetWindowRect(proc.MainWindowHandle, ref rect);
    width = rect.right - rect.left;
    height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    // break foreach if an realistic rectangle found => main process found
    if (width != 0 && height != 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to work with Internet Explorer (1 instance, 4 tabs) - only 1 process with non-zero rectangle. With Google Chrome (1 instance single tab) though there were 7 process with 3 non-zero sized rectangles (all the same) - so doesn't work for that. I do not have FireFox so can't comment on that.

Comment: @PaulF made changes that 0 values are allowed but not in an rectangle what makes more sense. Does it now work also for chrome? By me its working, but i have chrome on a second screen open.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: As I said - I get multiple Chrome process all with the same (non-zero) width & height - but if this works for FireFox then great. The only way I found to locate the correct process for chrome & ie was to check the commandline.